# React pagination in componentDidMount()

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm working on a blog-like website and there is a page called PageDetail with the post and comments.

I fetch the comments with redux and set the state.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchComments(this.props.match.params.id)
  this.setCommentsForCurrentPage()
}
```

My state is shown as below to do the pagination.

```
state = {
  currentPage: 0,
  offset: 0,
  slicedComments: [],
}
```

My slice function is as below.

```
setCommentsForCurrentPage() {
  let slicedComments = this.props.comments
    .slice(this.state.offset, this.state.offset + COMMENT_PER_PAGE)
  this.setState({ slicedComments });
}
```

And I pass this comments to the Comments component.

```
<Comments
  comments={this.state.slicedComments}
/>
```

My problem is; since the comments is set to the state async, setCommentsForCurrentPage function runs immediately, and it cannot find any comment prop coming from the redux.

What is the best practice for this kind of a problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does your `fetchComments` action look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using componentDidUpdate method in your Comments component. Since your props will change, it will trigger the rerendering and your comments should show up.`

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.userID !== prevProps.userID) {
    this.fetchData(this.props.userID);
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle function instead of `componentDidMount` to determine when to run `setCommentsForCurrentPage()`.  Compare the prevProps to the current props and if `this.props.comments` have changed, run `setCommentsForCurrentPage()`

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html